# WordPress plugin activation insert multiple raws

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am trying to insert multiple raw into database on plugin activation, and I manage to insert only one raw.
I can figure out how to add multiple raw for example 10 raw.

Below is the working code that is inserting one raw only:

```
function my_func() {
global $wpdb;
$_IL_TABLE_SETTINGS = $wpdb->prefix . "table";

$wpdb->insert(
    $_IL_TABLE_SETTINGS,
    array( 'id' => '1', 'options' => 'something', 'values' => 'something' ));
}
```

I tried like this but is not working for the second raw:

```
function my_func() {
  global $wpdb;
  $_IL_TABLE_SETTINGS = $wpdb->prefix . "table";

  $wpdb->insert(
    $_IL_TABLE_SETTINGS,
    array( 'id' => '1', 'options' => 'something', 'values' => 'something' ),
    array( 'id' => '2', 'options' => 'something', 'values' => 'something' )
  );
}
```

How i can add this values into your code:

```
$id = array('1', '2', '3');
$op = array('first', 'second', 'thaird');
$data = array('value1', 'value2', 'value3');
```

I will appreciate any help.

Comment: yes row, sorry i fixed my spelling mistake @mikemike

Comment: just try it with any loop

Comment: can u give me any example of loo to work for my code? i did different loops but seems i am missing something from them, can not get iot working @Dinesh

Comment: Please check My solution, hope that will work for this

Comment: @Tristup i updated my question i put my values into array at the bottom, can u help me to insert them into your code? thanks

Comment: Give me few mins so I can give you the code here

Comment: Have you checked it and did it worked for you.  Please let me know.

Comment: @Tristup it didn't worked, the tabel is emphy...

Comment: can u please check once again with the new set of code I pasted here.

Comment: @Tristup  thnak a lot it worked like a charm

Comment: Thanks and let me know if you have any issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        Here is the code which will work.

        $id = array('1', '2', '3');
        $op = array('first', 'second', 'thaird');
        $data = array('value1', 'value2', 'value3');    


        for($i=0;$i<count($id);$i++)
        {
            $wpdb->insert($_IL_TABLE_SETTINGS,array("id"=>$id[$i],"option"=>$op[$i],"values"=>$data[$i]));           
        }

        Please let me know if it didnt work for you.
```

Answer (score 1):

for example if you want to add 10 records then you can try `for` loop:

```
for($i=0;$i<10;$i++)
  {
    $wpdb->insert(
    $_IL_TABLE_SETTINGS,
    array( 'id' => '$i', 'options' => 'something', 'values' => 'something' ),
  }
```

of course you will need to add your dynamic data accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a loop into it and put the $wpdb->insert inside that loop.

Comment: that's the problem i couldn't manage to get a working loop, can u share my code how to that loop? @tristup

Answer (score 0):

```
    If value is stored in an array

    $arr=array();//containing the values you want to insert 
    $arr[0]=array("id"=>idvalue,"key"=>"value");
    for($i=0;$i<count($arr);$i++)
    {
        $wpdb->insert($_IL_TABLE_SETTINGS,$arr[$i]));           
    }


    if you want to store imaginari values 

    for($i=0;$i<count($arr);$i++)
    {
        $wpdb->insert($_IL_TABLE_SETTINGS,array( 'id' => $i, 'options' => 'something', 'values' => 'something' ));          
    }

    Hope you can relate your code with the above one, if no please let me know.
```

Comment: i have something like this how i can use in your code? $id = array('1', '2', '3');  $option = array('first', 'second', 'thaird'); $value = array('value1', 'value2', 'value3'); @tristup